# Future of Masterchef contestants

Tags: masterchef

In Masterchef US, most of the contestants continue their regular jobs after the show and some go on to start their catering companies or do something else cooking-related as a side job like offering private chef services. If these are the only practical applications of what they learned what do they gain from participating in *Masterchef*?

Comment: Which country? Masterchef is produced in 40+ countries, and the UK and USA have different formats to the Australian series, for example. Also, Australian Masterchef (and USA) winners get prize money and book deal, while the UK winner doesn't.

Comment: I meant Masterchef US. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

The winner of each season of *Masterchef* USA [wins $250,000 and a cookbook deal](https://www.realitytvrevisited.com/2017/08/masterchef-winners-where-are-they-now.html) - so participating 'gains' them the opportunity to win this prize.

There also comes a little bit celebrity from being on the show - and the opportunity to get paid for interviews and appearances, or just be noticed and get a job at a restaurant.